# Redirect error rows only when conversion fails

Tags: ssis, data-conversion, dataflowtask

I have a data conversion task in ssis in which I am changing datatype of a column and configured error output as "Redirect Rows".

But when I am running the package I am getting this, which is executing both success and failure part even though there is no failure rows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, but just because it's green does not mean any rows went there. It's green because it has succeeded and zero rows went down that path.